# Getting 401 Unauthorized in Spring security JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I was beginner in spring security JWT authentication, I am trying to authenticate the login using authentication controller. But when I am trying to test the api through controller I am getting 401 Unauthorized in postman

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.cognizant.auth.microservice.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**AuthController.java**

```
package com.cognizant.auth.microservice.controller;

import java.util.Objects;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.cognizant.auth.microservice.config.JwtTokenUtil;
import com.cognizant.auth.microservice.model.JwtResponse;
import com.cognizant.auth.microservice.model.LoginRequest;




@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody LoginRequest authenticationRequest)
            throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Inside");
        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        final UserDetails userDetails = jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        String token;
            token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        Objects.requireNonNull(username);
        Objects.requireNonNull(password);

        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
    }
    
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cognizant.authMicroservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>authMicroservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AuthorizationMicroservice</name>
    <description>Authorization Microservice that taking care to login and session</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can anyone help me where I was wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please explain why you are not using the built in JWTFilter that comes with spring security? Writing custom security is in general bad practice. Please do not follow blogs that contain faulty information and instead read the chapter called ”JWT” in the official spring security documentation.

Comment: @PIRANESH SAKTHIVEL please add the code for `jwtRequestFilter` and `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` to be able to also explain in my answer why you receive this error

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use a custom `jwtRequestFilter` to validate the tokens. In this case then you need to exclude this logic fron been applied to the authenticate request.

Use the following `if case` in your `jwtRequestFilter`

```
     protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
         if (!request.getRequestURI().equals("/authenticate" )) {
           ... Validate token or some other code
        }
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this configuration and it worked, you need to add the two configurations into WebSecurityConfig, thus:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    
    httpSecurity
            // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
            // don't create session
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            // allow anonymous resource requests
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", // swagger
                    "swagger-ui/**",
                    "/webjars/**", // swagger-ui webjars
                    "/swagger-resources/**", // swagger-ui resources
                    "/configuration/**", // swagger configuration
                    "/*.html", "/favicon.ico", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js")
            .permitAll().antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    // Custom JWT based security filter
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    // disable page caching
    httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)  {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/swagger-ui/**");
}
```